# Swift Morse Decoder

Tags: swift, switch-statement

```
var morseText = ".... . -.--   - .... . .-. ."
```

In English, it is "hey there"

```
var morseCodeArray: [String] = []
```

This is the array where individual morse code letters will be stored.

```
var currMorse: String = ""
```

currMorse is used to keep track of the current Morse letter.

```
for char in morseText {
  if char != " " {
    currMorse.append(char)
  } else {
    switch currMorse {
      case "": 
        currMorse += " "
      case " ":
        morseCodeArray.append(" ")
        currMorse = ""
      default: 
        morseCodeArray.append(currMorse)
        currMorse = ""
    }
  }
}
morseCodeArray.append(currMorse)
```

**Could someone please explain what exactly is happening in the *switch* statement?**

I know Apple wants *switch* statements to be exhaustive, and hence we have three *cases* here.

What I do not understand is the purpose of case #1 i.e. **case "":**

Why do we need this null/nil option? And even if we do, why do we then need to do this -> *currMorse += " "*

My programming-novice brain thinks we only need case #2 i.e. **case " ":**

Because all the other *char* options (like dots, dashes in morseText) will be covered by the *if* statement

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the morseCodeArray variable before. Now it is quite clear what the code does, case "" is when the previous word has been completed and added to the array and the next `char` is a " ".

Comment: I solved it - thanks to the extremely helpful answers here. Till now, I had heard stories about the helpful Stack Overflow community. Delighted to have experienced it first-hand! Was unable to find ways to run "lldb" debugger (Google says it's a very effective debugger for Swift). Also unable to install Atom Swift debug package. So tried doing it in Xcode Playground. Didn't get the clarity I wanted. So I went old-school and ran the loop step-by-step with pen-paper. And that was the Eureka moment! Wouldn't have been possible without the answers here though. Many sincere thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for char in morseText {                  // iterates thru all characters in morseText
  if char != " " {                       // .. in case char is not one space character 
    currMorse.append(char)               // .. .. append character to currMorse
  } else {                               // .. otherwise case char must be space
    switch currMorse {                   // .. .. but what if currMorse {
      case "":                           // .. .. .. contains nothing yet?
        currMorse += " "                 // .. .. .. .. add space to currMorse 
                                         // .. .. .. .. no need to empty currMorse here
      case " ":                          // .. .. .. contains space allready?
        morseCodeArray.append(" ")       // .. .. .. .. append space to morseCodeArray
        currMorse = ""                   // .. .. .. .. and empty currMorse
      default:                           // .. .. .. if all above fail
        morseCodeArray.append(currMorse) // .. .. .. .. just append to morseCodeArray 
        currMorse = ""                   // .. .. .. .. and empty currMorse
    }                                    // .. .. } end of switch
  }                                      // .. } end of else
}                                        // } end of for loop
morseCodeArray.append(currMorse)         // add all valid currMorse to morseCodeArray
```

so it parses `morseText` and checks each character for being *not spaces*, so it must be a *letter*, but if it contains a *space* then check if `currMorse` is *empty* and fill one space in `currMorse` to be added in the next iteration or at the end. Or `currMorse` is already one space? thats fine, so add one space to the result and empty `currMorse` (again), otherwise just append what `currMorse` contains yet and empty `currMorse` so it can't be added later, **so only letters and spaces are added at the end**.

This has a side effect, very obviously *spaces* from `morseText` are not passed to `morseCodeArray` directly and exchanged with spaces from `currMorse`.

Comment: THIS! This answer did the ultimate trick. The way you commented on each line - it helped me solve so many doubts about the processes happening behind-the-scene. Thank you Ol Sen!

Comment: welcome, was fun to figure it out. Thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 0):

In the morse code a single space is a **letter** separator.

The empty string case is to detect a  **word** separator, technically "does the word start with a space character" .

In the example string it considers the extra space between `y` and `t`

---

You can accomplish the same with `components(separatedBy` and `reduce`

```
let morseCodeArray = morseText.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce([String]()) { (result, string) -> [String] in
    if result.last?.isEmpty == true && string.isEmpty { // replace two consecutive empty items with one space
        return result.dropLast() + [" "]
    } else {
        return result + [string]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer vadian. But, right now, I do not fully understand the logic behind it. I have only just begun programming. Few weeks down the line, I hope to understand this answer. Always good to know more than one way to solve a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you don't unerstand why a certain piece of code is required or why it is acting the way it is, I suggest running your code in a debugger to understand what exactly is going on.

Add breakpoints at all branch statements and go through each line of code and each iteration to understand the effect of each line.

I just ran your code in a debugger. Wrote it in JS but it shouldn't matter. Here's what is happening:

1. `case ""` is required because there's a point in your `morseText` right after `-.--` whereby a null string is encountered. The case takes this as null and effectively converts it to a string with a whitespace with this statement: `currMorse += " "`
2. `case: " "` is required to deal with the newly created whitespace in the previous iteration. So it adds the `" "` as an element to your `morseCodeArray` array.

Comment: This line really, really helped understand what's going on in the code - "case "" is required because there's a point in your morseText right after -.-- whereby a null string is encountered". Thank you Jaimish :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement examines the value of the *currMorse* variable. If you take a look at the default statement it does two things:

1. appends the current morse to the array
2. resets the value of *currMorse*

If there would be no reset, the *currMorse* would grow in every further step and you would end up with something like this (just comment out the line):

```
....
.....
.....-.--
.....-.--
.....-.--
.....-.---
.....-.---....
.....-.---.....
.....-.---......-.
```

The switch case `case "":` is pretty much checking for the following case:

`char == " " && currMorse == ""`

If you put a breakpoint, you will see this happens exactly once.

Comment: This line really helped clarify things - "If there would be no reset, the currMorse would grow in every further step.....". Thank you Ben :)